# Am I responsible for the sins of others?

Tags: shirk

I work in a store where I sell movie CDs and also occasionally write reviews of some movies. Yes, I know I should find a more halal profession, but am I responsible for some person believing in the existence of Thor from Marvel because of my review or because I sold him that movie. I sold a guy a Thor movie just a couple of days ago, and I'm wondering if I'm responsible if he suddenly believes in Thor's existence and starts worshipping him?